# AWS constant 502 errors on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Everytime I create an instance I get a 502 error. This is even on single instance which doesnt have load balancer

1. creating environment
2. selecting php environment
3. sample application
4. Using the right roles etc

At this stage not even  deploying code just wanting to see the default php screen

Tried different regions. Tried looking at load balancers which I was so sure was the reason but doesnt make sense in single instance.

tried to make other environments with different things 5 times.

Tried looking at both http and https.

Should have shown the default php screen. It used to work at a point before this and show the screen.